# HTML5 progress bar "ending" styling

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I want to style the "ending" of the current progress of the HTML5 progress bar by adding small black dot to it, see the screen. So this dot must move as progress moves

[image]

But [the code I found](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/#article-header-id-6) here doesn't work anymore. It worked few weeks ago or so, but now it's not - [see the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZmgmj)

Maybe someone knows what happened or how to achieve my goal?

Thanks a lot!

P.S. Here is the HTML/CSS I use

**HTML:**

```
<progress value="1400" max="4261"></progress>
```

**CSS**

```
progress {

  /* Positioning */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  /* Dimensions */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;

  /* Reset the appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;

  /* Get rid of the default border in Firefox/Opera. */
  border: none;

  /* Progress bar container for Firefox/IE10+ */
  background-color: transparent;

  /* Progress bar value for IE10+ */
  color: #00D38D;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  position: relative;
  background: #00d38d;  
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value::after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: black;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: transparent;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #00D38D;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #00D38D;
}
```

Comment: You'll probably have to use JS

Comment: Yeah, I could use JS of course, but I'd like to do it with CSS, especially cause it worked before and just stopped

Comment: If it has such bad browser support that even the latest browsers have sketchy coverage, you probably shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a pseudo element to get this effect. Here it is using a gradient on the main style. (Tested only in Chrome)

```css
progress {
  /* Positioning */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  /* Dimensions */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;

  /* Reset the appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;

  /* Get rid of the default border in Firefox/Opera. */
  border: none;

  /* Progress bar container for Firefox/IE10+ */
  background-color: transparent;

  /* Progress bar value for IE10+ */
  color: #00D38D;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - 30px) center, black 15px, lightgreen 15px);
}

progress::progress-value {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - 30px) center, black 15px, lightgreen 15px);
}
```

```html
<progress value="1400" max="4261"></progress>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's awesome and helped!

Comment: Happy that it helped !!

Comment: Tested in Firefox. It doesn't work. It shows a blue progressbar without the dot.

Answer (score 1):

I read here that the pseudo css appears not to work with the progress element:

> I wish that I could have used :after (or ::after) rules instead, but
>   these pseudo-elements don’t work with the progress tags in any browser
>   that doesn’t use the polyfill. And no, :before doesn’t work either. I
>   have no idea why it doesn’t work, but it’s a shame — using them would
>   be perfect to get rid of the extra markup.

Found here: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/

I'm not sure why it was working before, I haven't been able to find a non JS way to emulate the effect of using the ::after css.

[Here's](http://codepen.io/pankajparashar/pen/qDKGo) a codepen from that article you referenced where it's not working as well.

They appear to be using the same method as you and it has no function:

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value:after {
    /* Only webkit/blink browsers understand pseudo 
    elements on pseudo classes. A     rare phenomenon! */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;

    width:5px; height:5px;
    top:7px; right:7px;

    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

You may have to implement some sort of javascript or use a different method other than the HTML5 progress element to implement this.

[Numbars](http://codepen.io/needim/pen/IJmhj) has some similar stuff to what you're trying to do, but you may need to modify it a decent amount to get it functioning the way you want.

Sorry this isn't exactly a solution, but hopefully you can find a workaround that's not too tough to create.